# Необходима ли запятая перед "или"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая перед "или" в данном случае?

Сергей, ты опять сегодня опоздал на пары. Изволишь объяснить своё опоздание(,) или сразу в деканат тебя отправить, там будешь объясняться?

Приятель, ты только 2 дня на испытательном сроке, а уже портишь нам третью деталь. Может, расскажешь, в чём дело(,) или мне позвать директора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во втором предложении запятая нужна, а в первом нет:

*Сергей, ты опять сегодня опоздал на пары. Изволишь объяснить своё опоздание или сразу в деканат тебя отправить, там будешь объясняться?* — обе части предложения вопросительные и не отделяются друг от друга запятой.

*Приятель, ты только 2 дня на испытательном сроке, а уже портишь нам третью деталь. Может, расскажешь, в чём дело, или мне позвать директора?* — придаточное предложение *в чем дело* нужно с двух сторон обособить, оно не участвует в сочинительно-вопросительной связи.

Comment: А я думаю, что везде вопросительные предложения, тогда запятая нигде не нужна.

Comment: @Sharon Как нигде? Даже придаточное закрывать не надо?

Comment: После может это я в спешке не проставил. Поправил.

Comment: Перед ИЛИ не надо, там альтернатива просматривается, а вопрос вроде бы ко всему содержанию.  Прилагается выбор варианта.

Comment: @Sharon Понятно, что говорим о запятой перед ИЛИ. Но как вы это представляете? *В чём дело или мне позвать директора?* Здесь можно не ставить.

Comment: Изволишь объяснить своё опоздание или сразу в деканат тебя отправить,..? Здесь не нужна запятая (что выбираешь?), а последнее предложение просто распространяет тему.

Comment: @Sharon Ну так мы же не об этом предложении. Вы написали: "...запятая нигде не нужна". Я спросил: "Даже придаточное закрывать не надо?" То есть в этом случае: *Может, расскажешь, в чём дело, или мне позвать директора?*

Comment: @Sharon Совсем не понимаю вашу логику. *В чём дело или мне позвать директора? Может, расскажешь?* Вот при таком порядке запятой нет. Или здесь: *Может расскажешь или мне позвать директора*. В исходном без запятой ну никак не вяжется.

Comment: @Александр Вы согласны с моим ответом таки?

Comment: Да, Максим, плюс.